# Differentiate between "String" and "Integer"

Tags: python

I am new to python and using Atom text editor/IDE. I am writing a simple code which takes input from user and tell whether it is Integer or not.Here is the code.

```
def check(string):
    if type(string) == int:
        return "Integer"
    else:
        return "String"

string=input()
print (check(string))
```

This functions returns "String" no matter what is typed i.e. 10 or hello.
Please help, what changes code needs, so it could differentiate between Integer and String.

Comment: Look into isinstance() and isnumeric()

Comment: `input` will always return a string. Even if you type `10`, that's just the string `"10"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using isnumeric

```
def check(string):
    if string.isnumeric():
        return "Integer"
    else:
        return "String"

string=input()
print (check(string))
```

Comment: This fails with '-1' or '+1'

Comment: I suppose you could check if the first character is an operator and if it is, check if the rest of the string is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it and if it fails, it's a non integer

```
def check(string):
    try:
        int(string)
        return 'Integer'
    except ValueError:
        return 'String'

string=input('Enter anything: ')

print(string, 'is', check(string))
```

If you're more of an LBYL person:

```
def check(string):
    if string.isnumeric() or (string and string[0] in ['-', '+'] and string[1:].isnumeric()):
        return 'Integer'
    else:
        return 'String'
```

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is usually not the best idea.

Comment: @rdas Doesn't mean it's wrong. https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def check(inp):
    if isinstance(inp , int) :
        return "Integer"
    elif isinstance(inp , str) :
        return "String"
    else:
        return "Other"
```

You should try using `isinstance()` for runtime type checking. Anyway `input()` always returns string.

Comment: This won't return integer if the input is `"10"`